# JDK11 Migration: Compilation error shown in Eclipse 2018-12 but code runs fine

Tags: java, java-module, java-11

While migrating from *Oracle JDK 8* to *Open JDK 11.0.1* using *Eclipse 2018-12* I obviously found another JPMS-related bug making it hard to work with external non-modularized *.jar's* within a modular java project. I tracked my problem down to the full example below.

The example was derived from the migration process of a real project (using the still non-modularized *javax.servlet.api*) which caused some headaches. It consists of four maven projects *M, N, Y and X* making up one java module each, and another maven project that makes up a non-modular java project *W*. I use maven and the *maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0*. My observations are:

- Eclipse shows errors in *M.java* but running class *M* with default options runs without errors
- if I include the artifact *w* as additional maven dependency in project *M*, the errors remain
- if I rename project *Y* to project *O* along with artifact, package name and module-info, no errors are shown
- if I remove the *requires w* in module *m*, no errors are shown
- if I make project *W* modular by adding a *module-info.java*, no errors are shown
- if I make project *W* modular by adding *Automatic-Module-Name: w* in *MANIFEST.MF*, the error remains

Obviously, re-declaring automated modules like module *w* in top-level projects **seems to cause problems with the built-in Eclipse compiler** and does not allow us to work properly with Eclipse (whereas running the project works well). In my opinion, this mismatch is another bug in Eclipse 2018-12 (along with the problems I described in [Automatic modules not found in Eclipse 2018-12 when project is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195765/automatic-modules-not-found-in-eclipse-2018-12-when-project-is-opened) and [Java module not found at runtime even with requires transitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215858/java-module-not-found-at-runtime-even-with-requires-transitive)).

**My question is: Can someone confirm this as a bug, or is it already known? For us it is a complete show stopper since our project depends on different libraries that are neither modular nor have they the *Automatic-Module-Name* attribute. And as long the Eclipse bug described in this post exist we are not be able to migrate further to JDK 11.**

*Sidemark*: We don’t want to configure our projects after checking out from SCM to get it running in Eclipse. For us, it was not necessary until now (*and that's actually really great when working with Maven and Eclipse, thanks to everyone who made that possible so far!*), and I hardly try to avoid to manually configure module paths of our eclipse projects or run configurations.

---

So, here is the complete and reproducable example:

**Project M** (modular)

```
// M.java
package m;
import com.example.n.N;
public class M {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("M");
        N.main(null);
    }
}

// module-info.java
open module m {
    requires n;
    requires w;
}

// pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
  <artifactId>m</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
          <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
          <artifactId>n</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>         
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
          <artifactId>y</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>             
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

**Project N** (modular)

```
// N.java
package com.example.n;
public class N {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("N");
    }
}

// module-info.java
open module n {
    exports com.example.n;
}

// pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
  <artifactId>n</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

**Project Y** (modular)

```
// Y.java
package com.example.y;
public class Y {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Y");
    }
}

// module-info.java
open module com.example.y {
    exports com.example.y;
    requires com.example.x;
}

// pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
  <artifactId>y</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
            <artifactId>x</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Project X** (modular)

```
// X.java
package com.example.x;
public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("X");
    }
}

// module-info.java
open module com.example.x {
    exports com.example.x;
    requires w;
}

// pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
  <artifactId>x</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
          <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
          <artifactId>w</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>             
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Project W** (non-modular)

```
// W.java
package external;
public class W {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("W");
    }
}

// pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenexample2</groupId>
  <artifactId>w</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Please do a *Maven > Update Projects … >* all to get everything in sync after defining the projects or changing your module dependencies. Also, please close also the non-modular project *M* after doing a *mvn clean install* since otherwise you would get the error described here: [Automatic modules not found in Eclipse 2018-12 when project is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195765/automatic-modules-not-found-in-eclipse-2018-12-when-project-is-opened).

Comment: Eclipse 2018-12 has a lot bugs ... I prefer with Eclipse 4.7.3 though it doesn't support Java 11. Or just use IDEA.

Comment: @Eric Wang: Thanks for the suggestion. For Eclipse, I filed a bug report since the problem described would be a show stopper for us when staying with Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543765

Comment: So far no bug in Eclipse could be identified. Access to an automatic module *must* be via the jar file. M needs a dependency on w for `requires w` to resolve. With these points observed compilation & running work as designed.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann: Access to the automatic module w _is_ done via the .jar file if W is installed in .m2 and closed afterwards. M _has_ already an (indirect) dependency on w (M depends on Y depends on X depends on W). In my opinion, both requirements are satisfied but Eclipse still _shows_ error messages in class M (whereas _runs_ this class as expected). Please see my comments in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543765.

Comment: After identifying the typo in the steps to reproduce (also visible in this question), an Editor-only error marker can be reproduced. This should not hinder development, but still needs fixing in Eclipse, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed Eclipse had a bug, which surfaced only when compilation was performed in a very specific order.

> **Background:** In the era of JPMS a package has different content
>   depending on which module is asking. In the example different modules
>   see different configurations for package `com.example`: from some
>   p.o.v. it contains a child package `n` in other perspectives it
>   doesn't. For performance sake, each result of such lookup is cached,
>   which caused the order dependence: which module first looked up
>   package `com.example` decided what contributions to the package were
>   known.
>
> *Curiously, the same JPMS that makes split packages illegal, requires a compiler to treat each parent package with multiple contributing modules as a split package, causing a significant increase in implementation complexity.*

*(Edited:)* The bug has been addressed as  [Eclipse bug 543765](https://bugs.eclipse.org/543765), the fix is available since release 2019-03.